# Sort an HashSet by two different values?

Tags: java, sorting, hashset, comparable

I need help.

I have an HashSet with type < ResultEmployee >.

ResultEmployee contains Employee(which contains id, name, email and so on) and two member named "halfHits" and "fullHits". I iterate over a Set of employees to find Strings that .equals or .contains a string I search for. The "halfHits" and "fullHits" member Count this results.

My Output:

Mia Smith, 0 FullHits, 1 HalfHits

Maik May, 3 FullHits, 2 HalfHits

Eve Hello, 2 FullHits, 0 HalfHits

Tina Troy, 3 FullHits, 1 HalfHits

and so on...

Example Output that I want:

Maik May, 3 FullHits, 2 HalfHits

Tina Troy, 3 FullHits, 1 HalfHits

Eve Hello, 2 FullHits, 0 HalfHits

Mia Smith, 0 FullHits, 1 HalfHits

and so on...

Problem:
I don't know how to sort a HashSet by two different values.
I tried with Comparable, but I failed. I don't know how to do something
like this. Please help me. I have no idea, how can I approach something like this. I tried something like this:

```
 public class SortHelper implements Comparator<ResultEmployee> {

@Override
    public int compare(ResultEmployee o1, ResultEmployee o2) {
        return ((Integer)o1.getFullHits()).compareTo((Integer)o2.getFullHits());
    }
}
```

But this only compares the fullHits and leave halfHits out.

Comment: It would be clearer if you showed the code of your classes instead of describing them. See also how to create a [mcve].

Comment: And specially the try you did with Comparable, to see what you did wrong

Comment: Consider using a [TreeSet with a custom Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: It is a fundamental property of sets that they do not have any ordering. In a `HashSet` there even cannot be an ordering (if not being a `LinkedHashSet` which only has an insert order). If you really have to sort something, you first need a `SortedSet` (for example a `TreeSet`). And then you can let your class implement `Comparable` if it has a natural order, or you can sort with a custom comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have the casting and I'm guessing at the implementation of `ResultEmployee`, but try

```
public class SortHelper implements Comparator<ResultEmployee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(ResultEmployee o1, ResultEmployee o2) {
        int result =((Integer)o1.getFullHits()).compareTo((Integer)o2.getFullHits());
        if (result == 0) { // Full hits were the same
            result = ((Integer)o1.getHalfHits()).compareTo((Integer)o2.getHalfHits());
        }
        return result.
    }
}
```

Then

```
Set<ResultEmployee> set = new TreeSet<>(new SortHelper());
```

The set will be sorted as you insert.

In Java 8, instead of defining `SortHelper` you can use

```
 Set<ResultEmployee> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(ResultEmployee::getFullHits).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(ResultEmployee::getHalfHits)));
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you very much...this worked for me :)